# How can I enable xUnit tests in Visual Studio 2012 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xunit

Is it possible to run xUnit tests the Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2012 Express? Or is there another, better way to do it?

I've seen Brad Wilson's [xUnit runner for VS2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/463c5987-f82b-46c8-a97e-b1cde42b9099), but it doesn't allow installation in Express. I extracted the VSIX and edited the manifest to allow support for VWDExpress which allowed it to install, but "Run all tests" doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Express edition of Visual Studio doesn't support third party addins.

Comment: ... But you could load the GUI and alt-tab to it - the status bar turns orange whenever it detects an assembly has changed